# How to privately store videos on sd card

Tags: android

I'm a beginner to android and need some help. The app I'm making lets the user purchase and download high resolution videos from a server. These videos are stored on the SD card.

This creates two problems for me:

1. Once on the SD card the files can be
   publicly viewed and copied to other locations.
2. When the app is uninstalled the
   files remain on the SD card and take
   up a lot of space.

**My questions:**

1. Can I make the videos private to my
   app? From what I understand storing
   to Internal Storage provides that
   privacy. However, Internal Storage
   is not the SD card and therefore
   provides only limited space - and
   the videos require a lot of space.
2. When the app is uninstalled - is
   there a way to make sure the videos
   are removed from the SD card.

Please tell me if you need more information! Thanks for being a great community!

Answer (score 1):

If you place a file on the phone there is nothing that can stop a user from getting access to that file you create.

Getting rid of any videos the application is easy just keep track of it.

I suppose you could encrypt the file which would prevent most users from downloading the file off their phone.

Comment: Thanks,

What do you mean by keeping track of the videos? Beacause I don't think I have any control over the uninstall process, i.e. I cannot decide which files should be removed from the SD-card when the user uninstalls. It'd be awesome if there was somekind of onUninstall callback I could override in my app. But I don't think it exists... anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt your videos using a block cipher stream.

[CipherOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html)

Comment: Nice! I was actually looking for this kind of class a couple of days ago. However, it only solves part 1 of my problem. Thank you so much anyway!

Answer (score 0):

you could always embed the videos in a sqlite database and then lock down the db.  That way when you uninstall it takes the videos with it.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a great solution! I will try this tonight. Do you have any pointers before I get started? Thank you so much for the tip!

Comment: only thing I can think of is to use a binary stream when writing the object to the db.